# Mean, median and modal

Tags: self-study

The following table represents the relative frequency of accidents per day in a city.

```
Number of accidents   Relative frequency
0                     0.55
1                     0.20
2                     0.10
3                     0.15
4 or more             0.00
```

Which of the following statements are true?

```
  I. The mean and modal number of accidents are equal.
 II. The mean and median number of accidents are equal.
III. The median and modal number of accidents are equal.

A.   I only
B.   II only
C.   III only
D.   I, II and III
E.   I and II
```

The answer given is c, but I don't understand why. The median is 0 right? But how do I know?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is self-study, I'll just suggest some hints: What is the definition of "median"? What does a relative frequency of 0.55 mean?

You didn't ask about I and II, but they can be answered by thinking about whether the mean can possibly be 0 in this case.

Comment: Median is n/2.Which is the middle value.

Comment: The median IS the middle value, but it is not N/2; in fact, since you have relative frequencies, you don't know what N is (and you don't need to know to answer the question).

Comment: @JacobTanTan don't confuse the median of a sample with the median of a distribution. You don't have any $N$'s here.